# Border around a hexagonal background image inside a div

Tags: html, css, png, border

In my ReactJs project, I have a `<div>` which has a hexagonal background-image.

I want to add a hexagonal border around this background-image. Is it possible to do that using css?

```
<div         
   style={{
       backgroundImage: `url("/images/eocs/aspiration.png")`,
       width: '120%',
       height: '0',
       paddingTop: '105%',
       position: 'relative',
       marginTop: `${eoc.topPosition}`,
       marginBottom: `-${eoc.topPosition}`,
   }}
</div>
```

Adding a border on `div` applies a rectangular border on it.

Here is the background-image, my requirement is to add a border on this image just outside the black colored border.

[image: here is the background-image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that with `drop-shadow` filter property

```
<div ...>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/i52ss.png" style={{
    filter: `drop-shadow(2px 2px 0 COLOR)
             drop-shadow(-2px 2px 0 COLOR)
             drop-shadow(2px -2px 0 COLOR)
             drop-shadow(-2px -2px 0 COLOR)`;
    }}
  />
</div>
```

[Example codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/upbeat-chatelet-4qsexi?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

**NOTE**: Only works with `png`